# Is there any API to get data from database into Google Data Studio through rest API only

Tags: looker-studio

Want to get the data from spectrum hub and use that same for report generation but, unable to get request data studio link for get method to pass it in postman with their respective parameters

Comment: Where is the source data available?

Answer (score 4):

You can build your own connector for Data Studio that fetches data from a certain REST API. See [guides and reference](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/) on Community Connectors.

Answer (score 2):

As there are different data sources available to connect with Google Data Studio, you may use any of them as the source for GDS Reporting.
What you can do is:

1. Pull out the data from the API and create a CSV file and upload it to GDS.
2. Push the API data into Google Sheet.
3. Push the API data to MySQL and then connect it with the GDS